# Getting this error while displaying even semesters

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Want to display even semesters but getting this error.It seems ok but am getting exception please correct me.

```
declare
cursor scursor is select rno,sname,sem from student;
srec scursor%rowtype;


begin


for srec in scursor
loop
continue when (mod(srec.sem,2)!=0);
dbms_output.put_line('Student name '||srec.sname);
dbms_output.put_line('Roll no '||srec.rno);
dbms_output.put_line('Semester '||srec.sem);
end loop;


end;
```

**Exception**

```
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 11:
PLS-00103:
Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a `select` instead of a cursor?

In any case, put the logic in the query itself:

```
declare cursor scursor is
    select rno, sname, sem
    from student
    where mod(sem, 2) = 0;
srec scursor%rowtype;
```

This is also more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the right syntax of `CONTINUE` in the loop

```
IF mod(srec.sem,2)!=0 THEN
   CONTINUE;
END IF;
```